# compare two reference in Mongo?

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, mongodb

i face some problem with mongodb

i have user Schema in my database which has two reference one 
for result and another for test

```
var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
username: String,
email: { type: String , unique: true , required: true} ,
password: String,
gender: { type: String , required: true},
memberShip: {type: String , required: true , default: "pro"},
results: [
   {
    type:  mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "Result"
   }
], 
tests: [
   {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "Test"
   }

],
resetPasswordToken: String,
resetPasswordExpiration: Date
});
```

and this is my result schema

```
var resultSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
testName: String,
testId: Number,
totalResult: Number
})
```

and this is test schema

```
var testSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
testNumber: Number 
})
```

the problem is i want to access these references in html to show the value to user 
i tried to use populate but i didn't work

```
app.get("/test/:id" , isLoggedIn ,function(req , res){
User.findById(req.params.id).populate("results").populate("tests").exec( 
function(error , userResult){
if(error && !userInfo){
  console.log(error)
  req.flash("error" , "error")
  res.redirect("back")
} else {
  res.render("testPage" , {userResult: userResult})
}
})
})
```

Comment: What problem are you facing ? Any errors ?

Comment: no there is no error but also the value  doesnt show in html

Comment: Can you log your userResult and put it in the question and also can you show how you have modeled your schema

Comment: yes it print fine but when i try to access the value of testNumber it print undefined i think i have mistake to access ref value

Comment: i print like this     console.log(userResult.tests.testNumber)

Answer (score 0):

I created this test for your problem(based in your schemas):

```
  //create test object
  let test = new TestModel({
    testNumber:10,
  });

  let testSaved = await test.save()
    .then((result) => {
      console.log(result);
      return result;
    }).catch((err) => {
      console.log(err)
    });

  //create result object
  let result = new ResultModel({
    testName: 'test name',
    testId: 10,
    totalResult: 20
  });

  let resultSaved = await result.save()
    .then((result) => {
      console.log(result);
      return result;
    }).catch((err) => {
      console.log(err)
    });

  //create user object with result and test objects
  let user = new UserModel({
    username: 'test name',
    email: 'test@test.com' ,
    password: '123abc',
    gender: 'male',
    memberShip: "pro",
    results: [resultSaved._id],
    tests: [testSaved._id],
    resetPasswordToken: 'teste',
    resetPasswordExpiration: new Date()
  });

  return await user.save()
    .then((result) => {
      console.log(result);
      return result;
    }).catch((err) => {
      console.log(err)
    });
```

This the data that was generated in the database:

[image: database data]

After this I executed the populate command:

```
UserModel.findById({_id:"5b4a7169df0fdf56bf3574fb"})
    .populate('results')
    .populate('tests')
    .then((result) => {
    console.log('---RESULTS---');
    console.log(result._doc.results);
    console.log('---TESTS---');
    console.log(result._doc.tests);
  }).catch((err) => {
    console.log(err)
  });
```

And it worked perfect:

[image]

Try to execute this code, I believe that will solve your problem.

Mongoose Documentation about populate function: [Mongoose Populate](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html)